# OrientDB Update runs into JVM memory issue 'Cannot allocate memory'

Tags: jvm, orientdb, java

I just updated my **OrientDB** to the **latest Version**. So I just took the complete folder to test it without my custom settings. Then I tried to start the new version with:

```
sh server.sh

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000e04a0000, 357957632, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 357957632 bytes for committing reserved memory.

# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/ubuntu/orientdb/bin/hs_err_pid1885.log
```

But as you can see there is trouble with the JVM. Something with memory. But I did not  change any setting. So how can this come?

I also cannot rember to set some custom Java settings on my system. Is there a way to check it?

### What I changed

```
<properties>
        <!-- DATABASE POOL: size min/max -->
        <entry name="db.pool.min" value="1"/>
        <entry name="db.pool.max" value="50"/>

        <!-- PROFILER: configures the profiler as <seconds-for-snapshot>,<archive-snapshot-size>,<summary-size> -->
        <entry name="profiler.enabled" value="true"/>
        <!-- <entry name="profiler.config" value="30,10,10" /> -->

        <!-- LOG: enable/Disable logging. Levels are: finer, fine, finest, info,
            warning -->
        <entry name="log.console.level" value="info"/>
        <entry name="log.file.level" value="fine"/>

        <!-- Memory -->
        <entry name="memory.chunk.size" value="‭20971520‬"/>
    </properties>
```

Comment: How much memory do you have?

Comment: 512 MB, ohh and I upgraded from 2.0.12 to 2.1.16. But again in 2.0.12 all was fine. =)

Comment: Just because something was fine in the past doesn't mean things don't change. You're running out of memory, so either get more memory or tune your (OrientDB and/or JVM) settings.

Comment: So which files I need to change. In the server.sh there is the Setting of 512mb already set. Does it need to be somewhere else?

Comment: If you have only 512MB of memory, you can't give it all to OrientDB.

Comment: So where to set it correctly, and what size? 50% like 250mb ?

Comment: The manual probably tells you all about the settings, as for the amount of memory...considering that you're running out of memory, I'd say "less than you're currently trying to give it".

Comment: What sort of device are you running this on? A Raspberry Pi? Most mobile phones have more memory than this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change one line in sever.sh from `ORIENTDB_OPTS_MEMORY="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"` to `ORIENTDB_OPTS_MEMORY="-Xms128m -Xmx256m"`

Comment: Indeed that works. But anyway added a feature request to autodetec it: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6065

Comment: Now after 2 weeks. I can say it runs very well. No errors or issues. Thank you again. This setting fixed the issue.

Comment: Okay the issue came back somehow. I tried many different settings. Hopefully I find out the real issue. In the log I get something like memory issue. But nothings helped to fix it.